# If $(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+d)^2=4(ab+bc+cd)$, prove that $a=b=c=d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+d)^2=4(ab+bc+cd)$, prove that $a=b=c=d$

$\Rightarrow a^2+2ab+b^2+b^2+2bc+c^2+c^2+2cd+d^2=4ab+4bc+4cd$

$a^2+2b^2+2c^2+d^2=2ab+2bc+2cd$

$a^2+d^2=2ab+2bc+2cd-2b^2-2c^2$

$a^2+d^2=2(ab+bc+cd-b^2-c^2)$

Then I'm stuck. But I feel like there is a relation I'm supposed to know or recognize here. But clearly I don't. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $(x+y)^2-4xy=(x-y)^2$

Comment: $(a,b,c,d)=(1+i,i,0,0)$ is a counterexample, with $i^2=-1$.

Comment: In which Field are you trying to prove this?

Comment: Wow. Thanks Michal. I'm wondering is this your intuition, experience or both? Because there's no way. I can recognize that relationship just by a cursory glance.

Comment: With some experience in proving inequalities you can guess that the only reason something like this could possibly hold is that it reduces to the form sum_of_squares=0. Or, in other words, that there is always an inequality LHS>=RHS and you are looking at the equality case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+d)^2$
$=a^2 + 2ab + b^2 + b^2 + 2bc + c^2 + c^2 + 2cd + d^2$

Hence:
$(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+d)^2-4(ab+bc+cd)$
$=a^2 - 2ab + b^2 + b^2 - 2bc + c^2 + c^2 - 2cd + d^2$
$=(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2$

This latter is a sum of squares, and can only be zero, if all squares are zero:

$a-b=0$ AND
$b-c=0$ AND
$c-d=0$

Simply said: $a=b=c=d$

Obviously, your numbers need to be real (not complex) or the whole thing makes no sense :-)

Comment: I think you're mistaken on a small detail: `===` does not imply `=0`. Eg, when all are equal to `2`, you get 48 on both sides, which is still a valid solution.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne: you are right, I have improved my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Solving $(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+d)^2=4(ab+bc+cd)$ for $a$ gives us a quadratic with discriminant $-4 (b^2 - 2 b c + 2 c^2 - 2 c d + d^2)=-4((b-c)^2+(c-d)^2)\le0$. If we seek real solutions, then the discriminant must be zero and so $b=c=d$. The original equation then simplifies to $(a - d)^2=0$ and so $a=d$.